# how to configure mongodb with x509

Tags: mongodb, ssl, authorization, x509, pem

I was following the guide

> (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)

Centos root directory

cd /etc/ssl/

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out mongodb-cert.crt -keyout mongodb-cert.key
```

2.

```
cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.crt > mongodb.pem
```

vi /etc/mongod.conf

```
net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   ssl:
     mode: requireSSL
     PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
security:
   authorization: enabled
   clusterAuthMode: x509
```

and I did that but It's not start

this result

> Restarting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed. See 'systemctl status mongod.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Comment: Please post the error message from the log, or try to start it manually. Also what version and distribution of MongoDB ? Remember that certain distributions of MongoDB does not support SSL. Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem, If I want to ssl, It need to CA(certificate authority)pem